# Display cards in a grid container with MUI

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to display cards in a container spaced evenly but starting from the middle. Is there a way to do so with Material UI react?
Right now I this:

```
Container maxWidth={false} disableGutters>
      <Box style={styles.background}>
      <Grid spacing={0} container>
        <Grid item sm='12' lg='4' xs='12' textAlign={'center'} justifyContent={'center'}>
          <HowToCard title="" 
          description='Entre le numéro de téléphone de la personne que tu aimes' />
        </Grid>
        <Grid textAlign={'center'} item sm='12' lg='4' xs='12'>
          <HowToCard title="" 
          description='La personne que tu aimes est inscrite sur le site'/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid textAlign={'center'} item sm='12' lg='4' xs='12'>
          <HowToCard title="" 
          description='Vous serez tous les deux prévenus si vous vous aimez mutuellement !'/>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      </Box>
    </Container>
```

But it makes my first card start at the edge on the left and then the second one is not centered and the third one is not as well. I would like the first card and the third card to be placed symmetrically compared to the middle one that would be in the center of the screen.
Something like this: [image: cards well spaced]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly set `width` of you `<HowToCard>` and then modify your code like this

```
<Container maxWidth={false} disableGutters>
   <Box style={styles.background}>
      <Grid sx={{flexGrow:1}} spacing={0} container justifyContent="space- 
       evenly">
        <Grid  item >
          <HowToCard title="" 
          description='Entre le numéro de téléphone de la personne que tu 
          aimes' />
        </Grid>
        <Grid  item >
          <HowToCard title="" 
          description='La personne que tu aimes est inscrite sur le site'/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid  item >
          <HowToCard title="" 
          description='Vous serez tous les deux prévenus si vous vous aimez 
          mutuellement !'/>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
  </Box>
</Container>
```